# Behat features - Calculated expected value

Tags: testing, bdd, behat

I am using Behat tests to test a 3rd party web service for billing gift cards. Each test sends a billing request to the web service with an amount, and gets the remaining balance back. Is there a way in my feature to have the expected response be a variable? For example:

1. Call get card balance.
2. Bill card for 5 dollars. Expected balance returned should be the original balance minus 5.
3. Bill card for 10 dollars. Expected balance should be the previous balance minus 10.

I have been using the "Examples" method to create a table of values to pass into the test and the expected results, but each time I perform a test I have to update the whole table of response values. I would prefer to only have to update the first value in the table and have the rest calculated. Is this possible, and if so, how?

Below is an example of what I am hoping to accomplish:

```
| amount | result                            |
|    5   |  100                              |
|   10   |  previous result - current amount |
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not very clear from the question what you want. If that is the fixed value you are aiming to assert against in your feature then the only way of doing this would be to set the initial balance from your app. Doing this via the '@beforeScenario' hook probably would be the easiest solution (since you can't do that every time in the scenario outline).

Alternatively, if you cannot modify the balance from the suite, the only decent option is to do it the following way. That might not look as concrete as asserting against the actual value, but technically this is the same thing. Gherkin language (if you can call it a language) doesn't allow any operations and scenario outlines are probably the most dynamic part of it.

**Context**

```
protected $balance;

/**
 * @Give /^I know the balance$/
 */
public function updateBalance() {

    // API call to get the balance…

    $this->balance = API::getBalance();
}

/**
 * @When /^I bill the card for (\d+) dollars$/
 */
public function billCard($amount) {

    // API call to bill the card…

    API::billCard($amount);
}

/**
 * @Then /^the balance should reduce by (\d+) dollars$/
 */
public function assertBalance($amount) {

    // API call to verify the balance was reduced correctly, don't forget to cast if necessary.

    if ($this->balance - $amount === ($currentBalance = (int) API::getBalance())) {
        $this->balance = $currentBalance;
    } else {
        throw new Exception();
    }
}
```

**Feature**

```
Scenario Outline: …
    Given I know the balance
    When I bill the card for <amount> dollars
    Then the balance should reduce by <amount> dollars

    Examples:
        | amount |
        |  5     |
        |  10    |
```

Comment: Yes, that is what I am currently doing. Unfortunately, the PM wants to SEE the result in the feature. She wants to see a results column where the first value is specified, and the subsequent values are the above result minus the value in the amount column.

Comment: Does it mean that this is what you needed or does it mean something else? :)

Comment: This is not what I needed, it is what I am using now. I have updated my example to show what she wants to see.

Comment: I though you were asking for that at first, but couldn't quite figure out. See the updated answer.

Comment: That solution I think is a happy compromise. I was hoping that there was something hiding in Gherkin syntax that would allow me to have dynamic values in the feature. Thanks for the help. My PM can be quite needy, especially now that she can read and write the test cases...

Comment: Ha, prepare for the worst if she can read and write them now!